# ExporttoPDF() failed with "Database Logon Failed" error

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In a sample console application, I read an xml file into a dataset, provide it to Crystal Reports, and export the report to PDF using ExportToPDF() method. My application fails with a "Database Logon Failed" error. Similar issues found at [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/097d8eef-eb46-40ea-987f-783b7f855876/crystal-report-logon-failed-on-adonet-dataset?forum=vscrystalreports) and [SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1877169) don't seem to work.

I get the following error and stack trace in my logs:

```
ConsolePDF Exception: Database logon failed.
ConsolePDF Inner Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004100F): Database logon failed.
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
ConsolePDF Stack Trace:    at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType formatType, String fileName)
   at ConsolePDF.Program.ConsolePDF() in D:\user\ConsolePDF2\ConsolePDF\Program.cs:line 519
```

In the program, I'm reading an XML file, loading it into a dataset and providing it to the Crystal's report (.rpt) file. Exception gets raised at report.ExportToDisk(...) :

```
try
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(fileName, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
    string pdfFileName = filename + ".pdf";
    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
    String rptLoc = reportLocation.Replace(@"\/", @"\");
    report.Load(rptLoc);

    ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Temp\ReportPDFSOXML.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

    string fullName = fileDir + pdfFileName;
    report.SetDatabaseLogon("user","password","server","database");

    // Next line is 519 - where exception was raised
    report.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, fullName);
    report.Close();
    report.Dispose();                               
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Info(ex.Message, "ConsolePDF Exception");
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        logger.Info(ex.InnerException.ToString(), "ConsolePDF Inner Exception");
    }
    if (ex.StackTrace.ToString() != null)
    {
        logger.Info(ex.StackTrace.ToString(), "ConsolePDF Stack Trace");
    }
    connPool.Dispose();
    sessionConn.Dispose();
    Environment.Exit(0);  
}
```

What can I do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

But you never use your dataset in this code ! Try to add this line like this :

```
   //Your Line
   ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Temp\ReportPDFSOXML.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
   //Set the report datasource, using your ds
   report.SetDataSource(ds);
```

Then, did you check your login / database / server informations twice ? The problem could just be there !

Regards,